# How to replace html dataset with variables

Tags: javascript

Hi,

I have this code to sort a html list:

```
 function sortList(listid){
  //some stuff
  elms.sort(function(a, b){
   if(a.dataset.age < b.dataset.age) { return minusone; }
   if(a.dataset.age > b.dataset.age) { return plusone; } 
   return 0;
  });
 }
```

this works fine but I want to modify it so I can use variables to work with different datasets:

```
 function sortList(listid,type,direction){
   //some stuff
   var typesort = 'dataset'.type;
   elms.sort(function(a, b){
     if(a.typesort < b.typesort) return minusone;
     if(a.typesort > b.typesort) return plusone;
     return 0;
    });
   }
```

but this is not working as expected since the sorting is all over the place. You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/ocymgrL7/2/

what is the correct syntaxis to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you means  to say, `a[typesort] < b[typesort]`?

Comment: not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to say that `a`  has a property `dataset` and that property, a.dataset, has property `age`, you can say `a.dataset.age` OR you can say `a.dataset[age]`

```
// Sort the lis in descending order
elms.sort(function(a, b){
 if(a.dataset[type] < b.dataset[type]) return minusone;
 if(a.dataset[type] > b.dataset[type]) return plusone;
 return 0;
});
```

See reference: [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `element.dataset.prop` is not all that bad. The verbosity of calling-out `dataset` makes your code more readable.

Your sorting can be simplified to the following. Keep in mind that this is a very simple example.

```js
/**
 *  Sorts elements in-place.
 *  @param {String} selector - multi-element selector
 *  @param {Function} sorterFn - comparator function used for sorting
 *  @param {Number} [direction=1] - direction of sort (1 = ASC, -1 = DESC)
 */
const sortElements = (selector, sorterFn, direction = 1) => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
  const parentEl = elements[0].parentElement;
  elements.sort((a, b) => sorterFn(a, b) * direction).forEach(el => parentEl.append(el));
}

// Sort by type then name and then reverse the entire sort.
sortElements('#list li', (a, b) =>
  a.dataset.type.localeCompare(b.dataset.type) ||
  a.textContent.trim().localeCompare(b.textContent.trim()), -1);
```

```css
li[data-type="fruit"]     { color: orange; }
li[data-type="vegetable"] { color: green;  }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li data-type="fruit">Apple</li>
  <li data-type="vegetable">Broccoli</li>
  <li data-type="vegetable">Carrot</li>
  <li data-type="fruit">Orange</li>
  <li data-type="fruit">Pear</li>
  <li data-type="vegetable">Raddish</li>
</ul>
```

You can get fancy by allowing vararg ("variable argument" using the spread operator) comparators:

```js
/**
 *  Sorts elements in-place.
 *  @param {String} selector - multi-element selector
 *  @param {Function} sorterFn - comparator function used for sorting
 *  @param {Number} [direction=1] - direction of sort (1 = ASC, -1 = DESC)
 */
const sortElements = (selector, ...comparators) => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
  const parentEl = elements[0].parentElement;
  elements.sort((a, b) => {
    let res = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < comparators.length; i++) {
      const { fn, dir = 'ASC' } = comparators[i];
      res = fn(a, b) * (dir === 'DESC' ? -1 : 1);
      if (res !== 0) return res;
    }
    return res;
  }).forEach(el => parentEl.append(el));
}

// Sort by type then name (in reverse)
sortElements('#list li', {
  fn: (a, b) => a.dataset.type.localeCompare(b.dataset.type)
}, {
  fn: (a, b) => a.textContent.trim().localeCompare(b.textContent.trim()),
  dir: 'DESC'
});
```

```css
li[data-type="fruit"]     { color: orange; }
li[data-type="vegetable"] { color: green;  }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li data-type="fruit">Apple</li>
  <li data-type="vegetable">Broccoli</li>
  <li data-type="vegetable">Carrot</li>
  <li data-type="fruit">Orange</li>
  <li data-type="fruit">Pear</li>
  <li data-type="vegetable">Raddish</li>
</ul>
```